# Solve PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in error log

Tags: php

This keeps showing in my error log:

[25-Apr-2018 20:30:51 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function prepare() on null in /home/vvhdbr/xxxxxxxxxxx.com/includes/functions.php on line 251

this is my code containing line  251

```
//Check if the user exists
**LINE 251** $stmt1 = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT userid FROM user_signin WHERE email = ? 
LIMIT 1");
$stmt1->bind_param('s', $email);
$stmt1->execute();
$stmt1->store_result();
$stmt1->bind_result($userid);
$stmt1->fetch();
```

Please what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: `$mysqli` is not what you think it is

Comment: I do not understand Smith

Comment: `$mysqli` is null, debug that

Comment: Check if, when you create the object, mysqli is returning some error. Look at the examples section of https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Database Connection Error might be reason. Check it. If you have connected to database then add that code to question. If you have not coonected to database then add below code and try

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');
if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
            . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

change variable to reflect your database credentials.